# How to clean up unused files in Wordpress hosted in Bitnami GCP?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, imagick, bitnami

I have hosted my WordPress website on gcp bitnami. Recently I encountered size issue, My website has reached 10GB of storage disk.
And I went to health info in WordPress, My database is just 54MB, my uploads is 450MB., my WordPress directory size is 3.5GB., what is causing this bloat?
What accounts for the remaining space?
I tried using cache plugins to purge cache.

[This is what I get if I run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3AwX.png)

```
sudo df -h
```

Comment: **1**. Please explain "website reached 10GB of disk" and "My database is just 54MB, my uploads is 450MB., my WordPress directory size is 3.5GB.". Do you mean that free space on your disk exosted and you resized disk to get more space? **2**. Have you tride to check size of log files `du -sh /var/log/` and analyze disk usage with utils like [ncdu](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/scr) or [duc](http://duc.zevv.nl/)?

Comment: yes, my disk space got used up and I resized the disk to get more space. I have edited the question to remove unnecessary details.

Comment: The log is just 20M

Comment: Thanks! Have you tried to analyze disk usage with utils like [ncdu](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/scr) or [duc](http://duc.zevv.nl/)?

Comment: Wouldn't it interfere with my website files?. coz it's a live website. just don't want to risk.

Comment: These utils were created to analyze disk space utilization and no more. Meanwhile, I'd recommend run any of them when the minimum number of customers expected because of additional load to disk io.

Comment: Tried with ncdu, was about to accidentally delete htdocs. thank goodness, I didn't. I don't know linux commands, and am skeptical to install 3rd party apps inside my live website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pagespeed Ninja Plugin was the problem** here. It created a new folder with *lot of js files* that amounted to around 3GB, and it had some .cache files under the plugin's folder, which again had around 4GB of files. I just uninstalled and deleted the plugin,.Now everything is alright.